# Couple of questions about iPad dev (from iPhone)

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, xcode

I am starting to develop an iPad app I have a couple of questions:

1. For UISplitViewController, how do I change the detail view controller (the one on the right with the controller on the left hand side)? Or do I need to have a Navigation Controller and continuously push view controllers?.
2. I have a UITableViewCell that's designed for landscape mode. Do I have to setup a separate one for portrait mode?
3. Is there a way I can zoom out in Interface builder so I can see the entire iPad layout (I am using XCode 4.0.2)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can change the two controllers by changing the `viewControllers` property of your `UISplitViewController`. If you want to keep the one on the left, you could do

```
[splitVC setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[splitVC.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0], myNewViewController, nil]];
```

Though I believe that won't animate the transition. For this, you could use a classical view controller as your right-hand view, and do the transitions inside of it.

2. No need to do a separate design if you've set your subviews’ `AutoresizingMask`s appropriately. See the documentations on this, it's quite handy for this kind of situation.

3. Dunno, I have a huge monitor, I'll leave this one to others :p